# Usb wifi not detect or connect in ubuntu

Tags: wireless

I have fall in an problem with usb wifi which ALFA UW07 is not detect in Ubuntu.I many time tried. But I didn't find wireless option in Ubuntu. And I could not connect usb wifi in Ubuntu. Please help me to connect in offline mode.
Thank you to read my problem.

Comment: Please insert the device and run the terminal command: `lsusb`. Next, edit your question to include the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.